# Plot chart in Power BI using latest values only?

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have a Stream Analytics job setup that takes data calculated on the fly from an event hub and pumps it into power bi

Each item that I plot is a value for a line chart.  These values get recalculated.  So I may have 2 values that relate to 04:00

One has been calculated at 04:15 with a value of 100

The second has been calculated at 04:30 with a value of 200

I need to tell Power BI to only plot the values that have the latest Calculated Date Time - in this case, only plot 200

However, as Power BI saves its data it ends up plotting both points. I need to use Stream Analytics as my user wants a live refresh.

I have tried various combinations in Q&A but none of them work.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Using streaming datasets in PowerBI can help to display a continuous feed of data, but it won't help for your scenario. I am thinking that maybe you can do Event Hub -> ASA -> SQL -> PowerBI.. ASA can make the calculation and save it in a SQL table that can then be displayed in Power BI. This way you will be able to filter on the latest value.

Comment: Thanks but this wouldn’t give me a live refresh would it? Direct query and sql connections only allow refresh every 15 mins dont they? I need a lot more frequent than that